# Update Dictionary object in redis cache using StackExchange.Redis client

Tags: c#, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am using azure redis cache and StackExchange.redis client to access it. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to update dictionary values in redis.

```
public async Task<T> FetchAndCacheAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> retrieveData, TimeSpan absoluteExpiry)
        {
            T value;

            var output = await _cache.StringGetAsync(key);
            if (output.HasValue)
            {
                value = _serializer.Deserialize<T>(output);
            }
            else
            {
                value = await retrieveData();
                await _cache.StringSetAsync(key, _serializer.Serialize(value), absoluteExpiry);
            }

            return value;
        }
```

_cache in the above code snippet is of type StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.

On initialization I store the dictionary object as

FetchAndCacheAsync("diagnostics", () => new Dictionary());

I have a function that will be called frequently to update the DateTime for a given key in the dictionary object.

**Question:** With my basic knowledge of redis cache I can only think of the following way to update a particular key value of a dictionary stored in a redis cache.

```
var diagnostics = FetchAndCacheAsync("diagnostics", () => new Dictionary<Guid, DateTime>());

diagnostics[key] = value;
_cache.KeyDeleteAsync("diagnostics");

FetchAndCacheAsync("diagnostics", () => diagnostics);
```

But it doesn't seem right to me. I am sure there must be a better way to do this. Any suggestion?

Comment: @MarcGravell Would really appreciate your insights on this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the Hash data structure supported by Redis?

http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#hashes

IDatabase.HashGet("diagnostics", "MyKey");

IDatabase.HashSet("diagnostics", "MyKey", "My Value");

Comment: I like this approach. Although having problems retrieving all the hash fields and values. Posting a separate question.